# Percorrer dois arrays em paralelo

Tags: python, array

Quer percorrer dois arrays em paralelo adicionando `:` entre eles:

**Arrays**

```
NOME = ['CARLOS','JOAO','PEDRO']

IDADE ['30','25','22']
```

**OUTPUT DESEJADO**

```
CARLOS:30
JOAO:25
PEDRO:22
```

**Tentativa**

```
rows = len(NOME)
for i in range(rows):
    print(str(NOME[i]+":"+IDADE))
```

**ERRO**

> TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se quer percorrer duas listas ao mesmo tempo, pode usar a [função `zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
nomes = ['CARLOS','JOAO','PEDRO']
idades = ['30','25','22']

for nome, idade in zip(nomes, idades):
    print('{}:{}'.format(nome, idade))
```

No caso, a cada iteração do `for`, as variáveis `nome` e `idade` terão um elemento das listas `nomes` e `idades`. A saída é:

```
CARLOS:30
JOAO:25
PEDRO:22
```

---

Isso funciona bem se as duas listas têm o mesmo tamanho. Mas caso elas tenham tamanhos diferentes, o `for` é encerrado assim que a menor das sequências terminar. Por exemplo, se as listas forem:

```
nomes = ['CARLOS','JOAO','PEDRO', 'FULANO SEM IDADE']
idades = ['30','25','22']
```

A saída é a mesma do código anterior.

Se você quiser mostrar todos os nomes, mesmo que a lista de nomes seja maior que a idades, você pode usar o [método `zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) do [módulo `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
import itertools

nomes = ['CARLOS','JOAO','PEDRO', 'FULANO SEM IDADE']
idades = ['30','25','22']

for nome, idade in itertools.zip_longest(nomes, idades, fillvalue=''):
    print('{}:{}'.format(nome, idade))
```

No caso, `fillvalue` define o valor que será usado quando uma lista for maior que outra e não houver elemento correspondente. No exemplo acima, um dos nomes não terá a idade correspondente, então eu defini o valor `''` (uma string vazia) para ser mostrado no lugar da idade. A saída é:

```
CARLOS:30
JOAO:25
PEDRO:22
FULANO SEM IDADE:
```

---

Repare também que mudei os nomes das listas. Afinal, se é uma lista que contém vários nomes, faz mais sentido chamá-la de `nomes` (no plural), do que `NOME` (no singular). Pode parecer um detalhe besta, mas [dar nomes melhores - para variáveis, funções, módulos, etc - ajudam muito na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação e exemplos, ficou muito didático!

Answer (score 2):

O erro ocorre justamente porque está tentando somar duas coisas incompatíveis. Você não pode somar uma lista com um texto. Mas o que deseja nem é isto, quer somar um elemento de uma lista com o elemento de outra lista, e isto não está acontecendo.

Você pegar elementos de cada uma das listas e não pegar um elemento de uma lista e a lista inteira do outro lado. Não tem porque complicar o intento se deseja algo tão simples.

```
nomes = ['CARLOS', 'JOAO', 'PEDRO']
idades = ['30', '25', '22']
rows = len(nomes)
for i in range(rows):
    print(nomes[i] + ":" + idades[i])
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/N3Zrt3). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/GetTwoListspy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/GetTwoLists.py).

Tem como fazer isso um pouco melhor, mas acho que ainda está cru para ver outras formas. Ver uma outra forma agora fará decorar receita de bolo  mas não aprender como se resolve um problema de forma simples. Eu apenas fiz o código ficar mais legível e tirei o que não tinha sentido ali.

A forma apresentada não é idiomática para Python, mas ela é simples e eficiente, por isso optei por essa forma. Em geral quem usa Python não prezam por eficiência, talvez pelo fato da maioria das pessoas que escolhem essa linguagem não seja programadores de fato. Muitos adotam por ser uma linguagem simples e não por ser eficiente, e não porque seria a melhor escolha para o problema. Mas nem todo mundo comete esse erro, alguns escolhem sabendo que está apenas resolvendo o problema simples e uma linguagem de *script* é mais adequada.

Note que estou falando de eficiência e não velocidade (ainda que seja quase certo que será mais rápido do jeito que eu fiz afinal não tem operação alguma extra, mesmo feito em C é algo desnecessário, só não garanto porque o `range()` também é uma abstração desnecessária e Python faz alocações onde não devia em vários casos), isto é sobre não fazer coisas desnecessárias.

Neste caso o algoritmo de um `zip` alocará memória sem necessidade, o que o problema pede é simples demais para usar um trambolhão. Um dos problemas do idioma que dá algo pronto é que as pessoas não percebem que aquilo pode ser bem ineficiente. Tudo o que faz algo não necessário não deveria ser usado, mesmo que pareça curto e bonitinho. Claro que o que estou dizendo pode ser criticado, esta é a visão de um desenvolvedor de software e não criador de *script*.

Defendo minha resposta como mais simples para quem está começando e ensina mais como fazer o algoritmo como um mecanismo e porque deu o erro em questão, sem abstrações, principalmente desnecessárias (se bobear até o `range()` não deveria ser usado). Embora a resposta do hkotsubo seja mais completa e idiomática para quem já passou desse estágio. Se fosse pra fazer coreto mesmo tudo isto estaria errado, você não teria duas listas e sim uma lista de objetos com todos os dados necessários.

Comment: Isso, eu gostaria de percorrer as duas listas em paralelo, cada linha de uma corresponde a linha da outra, mas deu esse erro quando usei seu script: TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got list.

Comment: Não dá: https://ideone.com/DQDV6i

Comment: Opa, deu certo agora, muito obrigado!