# Concatenar dois arrays 2D paralelamente

Tags: python, array

Como concatenar dois arrays 2D paralelamente retornando um array 1D, exemplo:

**ARRAYS/LISTAS**

```
lista 1 = [['a'],['b'],['c']]

lista 2 = [['A'],['B'],['C']]
```

**OBJETIVO:**

```
lista 3 = ['a:A','b:B','c:C']
```

**Tentativa:**

```
concat_array = [itm + ':' if not itm.endswith(':') else itm for itm in lista1 + lista2]
```

Comment: isso, lista 1 = [['a'],['b'],['c']], esqueci de colocar aspas simples no exemplo

Comment: Objetivo é obter uma lista assim: lista 3 = ['a:A','b:B','c:C']

Comment: alterei a pergunta...

Comment: onde lista3 = lista1 + ':' + lista2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o a função [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) para iterar sobre as duas listas e depois concatenar o primeiro elemento de cada sublista.

```
lista_1 = [['a'],['b'],['c']]
lista_2 = [['A'],['B'],['C']]

concat = [f"{x[0]}:{y[0]}" for x, y in zip(lista_1, lista_2)]

print(concat)
# ['a:A', 'b:B', 'c:C']
```

<sup>Código rodando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-414890-6333)</sup>

---

**Edit**:

Luis, se precisar de mais informações sobre o `zip`, [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/414323/6333) a sua própria pergunta pode ajudar.

Comment: Muito bom amigo, deu certo, obrigado !!

Comment: Porque você fez duas perguntas idênticas? [Esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/414318/6333) que você fez há 4 dias é praticamente a mesma.

Comment: na outra a lista é 1D e nessa e 2D, são listas dentro de listas.

Comment: O conceito é o mesmo Luis. Se você entender como resolver o problema de percorrer as listas paralelamente, acessar sublistas é fácil. Se você está com dificuldades não tem problema, a comunidade está aqui para ajudar, apenas tome cuidado para entender bem o conceito para que você possa utilizá-lo sem dúvidas quando precisar. :D Se você precisar posso elaborar uma explicação mais detalhada para entender o que fiz..

Comment: Opaa, muito obrigado, sua solução me ajudou bastante já, vou ler mais conteúdos sobre listas em python, não precisa se dar ao trabalho !!!