# Obter quantas vezes cada elemento de uma lista se repete

Tags: python

Eu tenho o seguinte array:

```
CLIENTE = ['MARIA','JOAO','MARIA','JOAO']
```

Eu gostaria de fazer o seguinte:

```
{'MARIA' : 2, 'JOAO': 2}
```

Tentei usar a biblioteca `from collections import Counter`, porém fez um *count* em cada letra do array.

Comment: Como assim "em cada letra"? Poderia mostrar exatamente como fez? Não faz sentido considerar as letras separadamente.

Comment: Acredito que seja por que o array é preenchido por um select no banco de dados

Comment: Luis, o `Counter` só vai fazer a contagem de cada letra se vc passar uma string. Se passar a lista diretamente, isso não acontece, independente de onde foi gerada a lista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você executar o código a seguir:

```
import collections

CLIENTE = ['MARIA','JOAO','MARIA','JOAO']
resultado = collections.Counter(CLIENTE)
print(resultado)
```

[exemplo funcionando](https://repl.it/repls/DramaticMediumpurpleProperty)

Comment: Felipe, por que converteu o resultado para `dict`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, porque, caso contrário, ele vai retornar um tipo Counter e não um dicionário, como foi solicitado na pergunta.

Comment: Bom, `Counter` é uma subclasse de `dict`, então por definição ela mesma já é um `dict`:D

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss verdade, resposta editada, valeu pelo toque (:

Answer (score 2):

Não sei como você usou o [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), mas funciona sim. Basta passar a lista diretamente para ele:

```
from collections import Counter

clientes = [ 'MARIA', 'JOAO', 'MARIA', 'JOAO' ]
counter = Counter(clientes)
print(counter)
```

Saída:

```
Counter({'MARIA': 2, 'JOAO': 2})
```

---

E [como eu já disse em outra pergunta sua](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/414323/112052), procure dar nomes mais significativos para as variáveis. Se é uma lista com vários clientes, é melhor que ela se chame `clientes` (plural, dá a entender que tem mais de um), em vez de `CLIENTE` (singular, dá a entender que se refere a apenas um). Pode parecer um detalhe besta, mas [nomes melhores ajudam muito na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad).